# Настройка chroot для sftp и rsync через rssh

Tags: ubuntu, gulp, sftp, rsync, chroot

Я настраиваю gulp-rsync через rssh в ubuntu
Хочу что бы у пользователя была возможность sftp и rsync без доступа к ssh и прочим протоколам.

Вопрос как сделать так что бы пользователи не могли просматривать другие директории

В общем допустим я создаю пользователя

```
useradd -m -d /var/www/DOMAIN.RU/ -s /usr/bin/rssh USERNAME
passwd USERNAME
```

Дальше если сразу соединиться по SFTP то пользователь находится в нужной дериктории но он может выйти в из нее допустим так

```
cd /
```

Дальше я правлю файл /etc/rssh.conf что бы там настроить chroot для пользователя и тут начинается интересное

```
allowsftp
allowrsync

umask = 022

chrootpath = /var/www/DOMAIN.RU
user=USERNAME:011:000110:"/var/www/DOMAIN.RU"  # both with chroot
```

После этого сохраняю файл перезагружаю apache и пользователь не может соединится по SFTP пишет

```
Conecction closed
```

Comment: `chrootpath = /var/www/DOMAIN.RU` — а сам chroot-то вы в этом каталоге сделали? см. [одноимённый файл, идущий в комплекте с rssh](https://fossies.org/linux/rssh/CHROOT). p.s. когда устанете создавать chroot, обратите внимание на скрипт rrsync, идущий в комптекте с rsync. это гораздо безопаснее (потому что не умерло, как rssh, восемь лет назад, а [продолжает поддерживаться](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/commits/master/support/rrsync)) и значительно проще.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Здравствуйте я написал вам на почту проверьте пожалуйста.

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147707/rsync-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-rrsync)