# rsync как запретить выход из своей директории rrsync

Tags: apache, rsync

Я настраиваю gulp-rsync и сделал настройку rrsync
в файл authorized_keys я добавил следующую строку

```
command="/usr/local/bin/rrsync -ro /var/www/mysite.ru",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding
```

Все вроде верно если соединяться по SFTP домашняя директория /var/www/mysite.ru но теперь вопрос:

1. Как сделать так что бы пользователь не мог подсоединятся по ssh и остальным протоколам (для безопасности)
2. Как сделать что бы он не мой выйти из своей директории допустим он пропишет

```
cd /
```

Answer (score 0):

> в файл authorized_keys я добавил следующую строку

нет, **добавлять** строку не надо.

каждая строка в этом файле представляет собой либо комментарий (начинается с `#`), либо информацию о публичной части ключа:

```
опции тип.ключа закодированное.base64.содержимое.публичной.части.ключа комментарий
```

поля разделены пробелами, поля `опции` и `комментарий` могут отсутствовать. пример (содержимое поля с публичной частью ключа сокращено для наглядности):

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz...JvzajQ== это_мой_ключ
```

поле `опции` представляет собой список опций, разделённых запятой.

то, что вы привели в вопросе — это и есть содержимое поля опции. вместе с ними строка должна выглядеть так:

```
опция1,опция2,...,опция100500 ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz...JvzajQ== это_мой_ключ
```

---

ну и не забудьте, что скрипт, упомянутый в опции `command`, должен быть исполняемым:

```
$ chmod +x /путь/к/скрипту
```

---

доп. чтение:

- `$ man authorized_keys`
- `$ less /usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync` (сам скрипт содержит подробные комментарии)